# How to create a Folder with VMware SDK

Tags: xml, sdk, vmware

does anybody know how to create a Folder with the VMware SDK?
https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.Folder.html#createFolder

I actually do not know how the XML Format has to be. I have tried several formats I found in the internet but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what language you are using to create the app at your side. The managed object folder has all the definitions, methods and return types

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.Folder.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to do it with JavaScript and the "soap" module. Sorry but even with your reference to the managed object, I am not able to create a suitable XML for the CreateFolder method. Can you help me here?